# Align rectangle with text in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating the legend of a figure in Tikz, and would like to align two rectangles with text:

```
  \node(legend) at (1.7,-6.75) {Legend: }; 
    \node[right=0.5cm of legend] (myNode) {};
      \draw[](myNode) rectangle +(0.4,0.2);
    \node[right=1.5cm of legend] (myNode) {};
      \draw[](myNode) rectangle +(0.4,0.2);
```

[image]

I am able to draw the rectangles, but they seem to be aligned with their bottom left corner to the center of the 'legend' node. How do I align the center of the rectangles to the center of the 'legend' node?

Comment: Please (always) provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document} which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of drawing a `rectangle` after specifying its location using a `node`, the `node` itself is a rectangle by default. Just add the key `draw` to the `node` and specify the `width` and `height`. The reason why your rectangles are not vertically centered is that rectangles start drawing from corner adding two lengths to reach the opposite corner.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rect/.style={draw,minimum width=0.4cm,minimum height=0.2cm}]
\node (legend) at (1.7,-6.75) {Legend:}; 
\node [right=0.5cm of legend,rect](myNode1){};
\node [right=1.5cm of legend,rect](myNode2){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]